# Django Rest Framework request header based permission

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, permissions

I'm building a Django app with Django Rest Framework to host it on my organisation's domain. The domain implements a custom authentication protocol. When someone accesses the domain, say to app1.domainname.com, they are redirected to the organisation's login page (login.domainname.com) and they have to log in with their staff account. After the user is authenticated, the user is redirected back to their initial destination (app1.domain.com). The information of the user is then stored in some custom header fields of the HTTP request sent to the app. E.g.

```
GET / HTTP/2
Content-Type: 
User-Agent: ...
...
X-Username: johndoe1
X-Firstname: John
X-Lastname: Doe
X-Email: johndoe@domainname.com
etc.
```

I'm trying to implement custom permission for my REST API that looks for these fields in the headers, and then authorise the user based on their user information. This is what I'm currently having:

```
from rest_framework.permissions import BasePermission

allowed = ['johndoe1', 'dicksmith2', 'username3']

class CutomPerm(BasePermission):
    message = "You don't have permission to access this object"

    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
        print(request.headers)
        username = request.headers['X-Username']
        return username in allowed
```

But when I run the server, it seems like the custom headers are passed through to the backend. For some requests they are, but ultimately the user is not authorised because the `has_object_permission` method raises a `KeyError`:

```
[10/Mar/2020 10:03:29] "GET /api/obj/ HTTP/1.1" 200 81
[10/Mar/2020 10:03:29] "GET /favicon.ico/ HTTP/1.1" 200 11
{'Content-Length': '', 'Content-Type': 'text/plain', 'Host': 'localhost:8000', 'Connection': 'keep-alive', etc., 'X-Username': 'johndoe1', 'X-Firstname': 'John', etc.}
Forbidden: /api/obj/1/
[10/Mar/2020 10:04:35] "GET /api/obj/1/ HTTP/1.1" 403 6581
{'Content-Length': '', 'Content-Type': 'text/plain', 'Host': 'localhost:8000', 'Connection': 'keep-alive', etc.} # no custom headers here
[10/Mar/2020 10:04:35] "GET /favicon.ico/ HTTP/1.1" 200 11
Internal Server Error: /api/obj/1/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/path/to/project/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/path/to/project/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/path/to/project/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/path/to/project/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/path/to/project/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/viewsets.py", line 114, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/path/to/project/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 505, in dispatch
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)
  File "/path/to/project/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 465, in handle_exception
    self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
  File "/path/to/project/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 476, in raise_uncaught_exception
    raise exc
  File "/path/to/project/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 502, in dispatch
    response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/path/to/project/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/mixins.py", line 54, in retrieve
    instance = self.get_object()
  File "/path/to/project/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/generics.py", line 99, in get_object
    self.check_object_permissions(self.request, obj)
  File "/path/to/project/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 343, in check_object_permissions
    if not permission.has_object_permission(request, self, obj):
  File "/path/to/project/project/app/permissions.py", line 11, in has_object_permission
    username = request.headers['X-Username']
  File "/path/to/project/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/http/request.py", line 388, in __getitem__
    return super().__getitem__(key.replace('_', '-'))
  File "/path/to/project/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/datastructures.py", line 320, in __getitem__
    return self._store[key.lower()][1]
KeyError: 'X-Username'
```

Note that in the 2 header dictionaries printed out, the first one has all the custom headers but the second one doesn't.
I think this is because there are some redirecting happening behind the scene and the final request that gets to the rest framework permission check has lost all of its custom headers. Is there anyway to check for permissions based on the custom headers?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Django modifies the http header keys.

You have to access the header as:

```py
username = request.META.get('HTTP_X_USERNAME', None)
if username:
    # your logic
    pass
```

checkout Django header docs:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.META

Comment: Thanks, but this is not it. I get the same error when using META. Also, I cannot use None when not being able to access the header because I have to use the username from the header field, and it's certain that it's going to be there.

Comment: print the request.META dict and check what is in there. If you can't find the header keys there then either the client is not sending them or some other service is removing them before the request hits Django server.

Comment: I think it's the latter. I'm printing the META dict and it's basically the same as the headers dict. Maybe some middleware is redirecting back and forth and in the process, omits the custom headers. I just don't know how to fix it.

Comment: check the function which is redirecting the request. It should set the headers, also check if headers are preserved on redirection. You should fail the request with 403 if the headers are not present and back track where they get lost.